# How many integer solutions are there to the inequality $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 < 184$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 < 184$
$y_1>0$

$0< y_2\leq10$

$0\leq y_3\leq17$

$0\leq y_4<19$

Don't really know what to do with the inequality. Can I simply change it to $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4  + y_5 = 183$? If so, will $y_5\geq 0$?

Edit: So this is what I got, it may or may not be correct:
$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4  + y_5 = 181$
$y_1\geq0, 0\leq y_2\leq9, 0\leq y_3\leq17, 0\leq y_4<19$

(181+4)C4 - (181+4-10)C4 - (181+4-18)C4 - (181+4-19)C4 + (181-19-18-10+4)C4

Comment: It is interesting to note that y2, y3, y4 are all "small" and their sum is less than 184. So basically you consider all combinations of y2, y3, y4, their sum and how far apart each sum is from 184 (possibilities for y1).

Comment: Yes, and yes; that’s exactly how you should proceed.

Comment: The "trick" of replacing an inequality by an equality by adding a non-negative variable  is widely used, not only here but also in Linear Programming.

Comment: So what are the rules here for answering questions. This is obviously a homework problem. Am I supposed to send a complete answer like on stackoverflow, or should I give "hints" like I replied here but got deleted as an answer.

Comment: There are infinitely many integer solutions.  Presumably you want positive or non-negative integers.  Is zero allowed?

Answer (score 2):

For given values of $y_2$, $y_3$, and $y_4$, there are $183-y_2-y_3-y_4$ valid choices for $y_1$, so the number is $$\sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} (183-y_2-y_3-y_4).$$

We simplify this as follows (using triangular numbers):
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{={}} \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} (183-y_2-y_3-y_4) \\
& = \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} 183 - \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} y_2 - \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} y_3 - \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} y_4 \\
& = 10 \times 18 \times 20 \times 183-18 \times 20 \times \tfrac{10 \times 11}{2}-10 \times 20 \times \tfrac{17 \times 18}{2}-10 \times 18 \times \tfrac{19 \times 20}{2} \\
& = 658800 - 19800 - 30600 - 34200 \\
& = 574200.
\end{align*}

We can verify this by generating all of them using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
count:=0;;
for y2 in [1..10] do
  for y3 in [0..17] do
    for y4 in [0..19] do 
      for y1 in [1..183-y2-y3-y4] do
        count:=count+1;
        Print(count," ",[y1,y2,y3,y4],"\n");
      od;
    od;
  od;
od;
```

whose output ends with:

```
574197 [ 134, 10, 17, 19 ]
574198 [ 135, 10, 17, 19 ]
574199 [ 136, 10, 17, 19 ]
574200 [ 137, 10, 17, 19 ]
```

NB. This answer is almost identical to my other answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2166826/91818).