# How many integer solution to $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\leq184$with $y_1>0,\,0<y_2\leq10,\,0\leq y_3\leq17 $ and $0\leq y_4\leq 19$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many integer solution to the inequality $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\leq184$$with $y_1>0,\,0<y_2\leq10,\,0\leq y_3\leq17 $ and  $0\leq y_4< 19$

MY try:For two variable I could try to solve by graphical method but for this, I don't know.Thank you

Comment: Check this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509378/how-many-integer-solutions-are-there-to-the-inequality-y-1-y-2-y-3-y-4?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

For given values of $y_2$, $y_3$, and $y_4$, there are $184-y_2-y_3-y_4$ valid choices for $y_1$, so the number is $$\sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} (184-y_2-y_3-y_4).$$

We simplify this as follows (using triangular numbers):
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{={}} \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} (184-y_2-y_3-y_4) \\
& = \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} 184 - \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} y_2 - \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} y_3 - \sum_{y_2=1}^{10} \sum_{y_3=0}^{17} \sum_{y_4=0}^{19} y_4 \\
& = 10 \times 18 \times 20 \times 184-18 \times 20 \times \tfrac{10 \times 11}{2}-10 \times 20 \times \tfrac{17 \times 18}{2}-10 \times 18 \times \tfrac{19 \times 20}{2} \\
& = 662400 - 19800 - 30600 - 34200 \\
& = 577800.
\end{align*}

We can verify this by generating all of them using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
count:=0;;
for y2 in [1..10] do
  for y3 in [0..17] do
    for y4 in [0..19] do 
      for y1 in [1..184-y2-y3-y4] do
        count:=count+1;
        Print(count," ",[y1,y2,y3,y4],"\n");
      od;
    od;
  od;
od;
```

whose output ends with:

```
577797 [ 135, 10, 17, 19 ]
577798 [ 136, 10, 17, 19 ]
577799 [ 137, 10, 17, 19 ]
577800 [ 138, 10, 17, 19 ]
```

Comment: Note that this method only works because the sum of the maximum constrained values for y2-y4 are < 184. In some versions of this problem, where the maximums could sum to more than 184, this would overcount the number of solutions. Your answer is correct for the question asked, just warning future internet travelers.

Answer (score 0):

The generating function $f(x)$ with coefficients $[x^k]f(x)$ that enumerate solutions to

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\le k$$

under said conditions (the ones in the title *not* the details) for the $y_i$s is

$$f(x)=x(x-x^{11})(1-x^{18})(1-x^{20})\cdot\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^5}$$

it is straightforward to expand the binomials to give the answer in terms of binomial coefficients but I just used this line in [sage](http://sagecell.sagemath.org)

```
taylor(x*(x-x^11)*(1-x^18)*(1-x^20)/(1-x)^5,x,0,184).coefficient(x^184)
```

which returns:

```
577800
```

Using the conditions in the details, instead you use the generating function with different $y_4$ upper limit:

$$g(x)=x(x-x^{11})(1-x^{18})(1-x^{19})\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}$$

sage input:

```
taylor(x*(x-x^11)*(1-x^18)*(1-x^19)/(1-x)^5,x,0,184).coefficient(x^184)
```

output:

```
550620
```